# What products can I use to repair large holes in plaster?

Tags: repair, walls, plaster, patch

I have a roughly 4'x 3' hole in plaster wall.  I've seen few youtube videos about how to repair it, but none of them say what product/mix they use.  I've read about using DAP Plaster Wall Patch, but it's not carried by most stores anymore.  Neither is structalite.  Any other product I can use instead of actual plaster?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, but there's an older question that predates this policy that should answer your question. I hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: @BMitch It sounds like he doesn't have cracks, he has a big hole. He also seems to think he can patch it directly rather than use drywall. He needs to either truly plaster (base coat/finish coat over lath) or he needs a drywall patch. I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: [This question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/40879/2196) covers patching the hole itself. Asking "what products" tends to be either off topic or full of deleted spam answers.

Comment: Where are you located? I googled the DAP plaster patch and it looks like it's sold by Lowe's, Ace Hardware, Amazon.com, Grainger and Walmart, so it should be readily available online if not in a brick-and-mortar store.

Comment: @BMitch None of these questions/answers say what plaster or what mix of joint compound/sand/cement (?) they use.  They just say to plaster it or to use drywall.  Ditto with multiple YT videos where they show how it's done.

Comment: @NiallC.I'm in Indianapolis.  None of the local stores carry it, and I'm not sure that the "wall patch" is the right product for a total re-plaster.  Amazon and Walmart have it but it's a bit pricey and the delivery takes some time.

Comment: See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Comment: @BMitch  no need for me to waste time on BS.  This site isn't the only game in town.